# Flask-Marshmallow nested schema with many=true not working

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, marshmallow

I'm trying to serialize an object holding a collection of objects but the collection is not serialized correctly.

The documentation tells me that when dealing with iterable collections of objects set many=True.

I did the same thing. These are my schemas:

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema

from app.institute.schema import InstituteSchema


class ResultRequestSchema(Schema):
    """Resultrequest"""

    class Meta:
        ordered = True

    resultRequestId = fields.Number(attribute="result_request_id")
    startYear = fields.Number(attribute="start_year")
    endYear = fields.Number(attribute="end_year")
    type = fields.String(attribute="type")
    institutes = fields.Nested(InstituteSchema, attribute="institutes", many=True)
```

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema



class InstituteSchema(Schema):
    """Institute"""

    class Meta:
        ordered = True

    instituteId = fields.Number(attribute="institute_id")
    name = fields.String(attribute="name")
    brin = fields.String(attribute="brin")
    city = fields.String(attribute="city")
```

My models if needed:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from app import db  # noqa
from app.result_request.model import result_request_institute_table

class Institute(db.Model):
    """Institute"""

    __tablename__ = "institute"

    institute_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    brin = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    city = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    resultrequests = relationship('ResultRequest', secondary=result_request_institute_table)
```

```
result_request_institute_table = Table('result_request_institute', db.metadata,
                                       Column('institute_id', Integer, ForeignKey('institute.institute_id')),
                                       Column('result_request_id', Integer,
                                              ForeignKey('result_request.result_request_id'))
                                       )


class ResultRequest(db.Model):
    """A ResultRequest"""

    __tablename__ = "result_request"
    result_request_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    start_year = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    end_year = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    type = Column(Enum("TOPIC", "SENTIMENT", "UNKNOWN", name="type"), default="UNKNOWN")
    institutes = relationship('Institute', secondary=result_request_institute_table)

    result = relationship('Result')
```

The resultrequest object has a collection of institute objects. In the swagger documentation the field is not presented as a collection but only as a single object.

```
{
  "resultRequestId": 0,
  "startYear": 0,
  "endYear": 0,
  "type": "string",
  "institutes": {
    "instituteId": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "brin": "string",
    "city": "string"
  }
}
```

should be

```
{
  "resultRequestId": 0,
  "startYear": 0,
  "endYear": 0,
  "type": "string",
  "institutes": [{
    "instituteId": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "brin": "string",
    "city": "string"
  }]
}
```

Comment: try to remove attribute="institutes"

Comment: Maybe try type hinting `institutes: List = relationship(...` in the model definition.